# Confused about object relationships

Tags: oop, object, modeling

In object oriented programming we have uses, has-a, is-a relationships. I wonder what would be the relation between earth and the sun, Earth revolves around the sun?

What is the best way of learning object oriented analysis, design and programming?

Comment: add another Object: "Solarsystem" and then you just have Solarsystem has Planet (Earth, Mars, Pluto, etc.) and has Star (Sun)

Comment: but what's the relationship between stars and planets particularly between sun and the earth?

Comment: in my example none. The question is what you want to achieve. If you want to roughly calculate the orbit you would add a 'Planet uses-a Star' and if the planet knows the star it revolves around it could calculate a stable orbit. Creating Object relations without a purpose beforehand makes no sense. Think about your goal first and create the object hierarchy as needed. For each and every hierarchy it will be possible to find a new 'example' which won't fit...

Comment: i want to make a simulation off solar system so how could i do that? what should i learn? i am very confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Objects, classes and *is-a* relationships**

In your object oriented domain model there are two main objects:

- an object `Earth` of class `Planet` (instantiation, is-a)
- an object `Sun` of class `Star` (instantiation, is-a)
- `Planet` and `Star` are special kinds of [`CelestialObject`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_object) (specialization, is-a)

**Association of classes and objects**

There is an association between `Sun` and `Earth`: `Earth` rotates around the `Sun`, captured by its gravity.

If we think in more general terms,  any `Star` could have several `Planet` that rotate around. It may as well have no `Planet` at all.  Conversely, most of the `Planet` rotate around one single `Star`.  Let's keep it simple for now, despite recent discoveries, which have confirmed that in very rare cases a `Planet` could be associated with several `Star`.

Such association has two point of view:  from the `Planet` we can say `has-a-Star` and from the Star side, we could say `has-a-Planet`.

**How to represent associations in a world of objects ?**

A simple way to represent a *has-a* association is to keep a reference to the associated object.  This works only for singular association, e.g. the object `Earth` would keep a reference to `Sun`.

Another way to represent a *has-a* association is to keep a list (more generally, a container)  of reference to the associated objects.  `Sun` would then have a list of associated `Planet` composed of `Venus`, `Earth`, `Mars`, etc...

Sometimes an association could be more complex and bear some data that is unique to the link it represents.  For example,  `Earth` is associated with the `Sun` and it turns around it in 365,25 days. To keep things simple, you could just consider that it's an attribute of the `Planet` in the solar system.  But if we'd take this seriously, this duration is in reality not a property of the `Earth`, because the `Earth` also turns around the center of the galaxy but with a different duration.  It's not a property of the `Sun` either, because `Mars` turns also around the `Sun`, but in 686,96 days.

In such cases, you can consider that the association is itself a class. An instantiation if it would be an object with a orbit duration of 365,25 days, and has-a first extremity `Sun` and a second extremity `Earth`

**More about these core concepts**

To learn more about these core concepts, and in a language independent fashion, you could have a look at the [UML class diagram](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-diagrams-overview.html).  It's purpose is to represent exactly these kind concepts. You may also have a look at [this blog](https://blogs.mathworks.com/developer/2015/03/31/dont-get-in-too-deep/), which gives a nice object of classes for celestial objects, although it doesn't address the associations.

**How to use the model in a simulation ?**

You need to choose an OO language to implement your model. Keep a container of celestial objects.  Each of this object should have some coordinates, a rotation speed, and a method that updates the coordinates based on its rotation speed and the elapsed time.  Your simulation would then consist of a loop (representing the elapsed time), and at each iteration, you'd go through your list of celestial objects and for each one update the coordinates, and display the result.

Comment: Thanks for help christophe. Can u recommend a book for object oriented thinking?

Comment: I liked Object Oriented Analysis & design from Grady Booch (perhaps a little bit outdated now) and UML distilled from Martin Fowler.  Or the book on OO  in the "head first" collection, which is more funny to read.